# ruby on rails clients model vs signup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, validation

I have an app that I'm developing where there is a Client model which allows the admin to create, edit and update new clients which I have working just fine. However, now I need to add a client sign up process that allows new clients to sign up thus creating their account.

I have a "Welcome" model that allows shows the promo page, provides new clients with a form to sign up for select Plans and lets them recover a lost password.

However, the signup form is very similar to the new form within the client model.
In my welcome_controller I have this:

```
def signup
    # I provide the client with a place to sign up
    @client = Client.new
end
```

My signup form/view looks like this:

```
<%= form_for @client do |f| %>
<% if @client.errors.any? %>
<div id="flash_error">
    <h2>Errors</h2>
    <ul>
        <% @client.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
            <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
</div>
<% end %>
...Form code...

<%= f.submit "Create My Account" %>
<% end %>
```

That's all well and good... BUT. I'm wanting the signup form to validate agains the Client model which it is doing (there is no model for "Welcome" just a controller). But when there are errors in validation it loads the clients/new route instead of the welcome/signup that they were on.

Is there a way that I can overcome this and validate against my Clients model but if this form fails take them back to the welcome/signup page they were on?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with:

```
if @client.save
  #manage saved client
else
  render "welcome"
end
```